# Open-source operating system alternatives/replacements to Android for Smartphones and their supported device list

Tags: linux, open-source, operating-system

Can you help me complete a list of the open-source operating systems that can be installed on smartphones in replacement of Android and their respective supported device list?

So far, I found :

- [SailFishOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sailfish_OS) (based on MeeGo Linux+Mer) ([SailFishOS supported device list](https://docs.sailfishos.org/Support/Supported_Devices), [Planned / rumored devices](https://together.jolla.com/question/136143/wiki-available-devices-plus-rumored-and-legacy-devices-running-sailfish-os/#136143-planned-rumored-devices) and [Adaptations/libhybris](https://wiki.merproject.org/wiki/Adaptations/libhybris))
- [Ubuntu Touch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Touch) (based on Ubuntu Linux) ([Ubuntu Touch devices](https://devices.ubuntu-touch.io/))
- [PostmarketOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostmarketOS) (based on Alpine Linux) ([PostmarketOS device list](https://wiki.postmarketos.org/wiki/Devices))
- [Manjaro-ARM](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Manjaro-ARM) (based on Arch Linux) ([Manjaro-ARM supported device list](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Manjaro-ARM#Supported_Devices))
- [Mobian](https://www.mobian-project.org) (based on Debian Linux) ([Mobian supported device list](https://wiki.mobian-project.org/doku.php?id=devices))
- [LineageOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LineageOS) (based on Android-GoogleApps) ([LineageOS supported device list](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/))
- [LineageOS for microG](https://lineage.microg.org/) (based on Android-GoogleApps+microG) ([LineageOS devices](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/))
- [/e/OS](https://e.foundation/e-os/) (based on LineageOS for microG-Google) ([/e/OS device list](https://doc.e.foundation/devices))

Android Apps support :

- SailFishOS can run Android apps with via [the proprietary Dalvik Turbo VM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sailfish_OS#Using_Android_software_running_on_Sailfish_OS).
- [Anbox](https://docs.anbox.io) can be used to run Android apps in a LXC container on Linux distrubutions for which `Anbox` has been packaged for.
- [Waydroid](https://docs.waydro.id) can also be used to run Android apps in a LXC container on Linux distrubutions for which `Waydroid` has been packaged for.
- LineageOS : you have to install the [F-Droid app store](https://f-droid.org/) manually than you will be able to install the [Aurora Store](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.aurora.store/) (A Google Playstore Client) from the F-Droid app store.
- LineageOS for microG provides the [F-Droid app store](https://f-droid.org/) with which you can install the [Aurora Store](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.aurora.store/) (A Google Playstore Client) from the F-Droid app store.
- /e/OS provides the [F-Droid app store](https://f-droid.org/) and [/e/Installer](https://e.foundation/e-os-available-applications/) (official /e/OS App store), you can also install the [Aurora Store](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.aurora.store/) (A Google Playstore Client) from the F-Droid app store.

N.B.: For SailFishOS devices, you have to [buy the SailFish X license](https://shop.jolla.com/) which is about $50 otherwise you won't get the support, the updates nor the Android App support.

Just found the [Tuxphones](https://tuxphones.com) site :)

Answer (score 2):

The [Wikipedia entry for FirefoxOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_OS), which was discontinued in 2017, lists a few more; e.g., H5OS, KaiOS of which I don't know the license terms.

Comment: Thanks. These are based on FirefoxOS which is based on the Linux kernel (such as Android). I'm more specifically attracted by Linux distribution based OSes.

Answer (score 2):

A list of Android-based ROMs from [here](https://gearjail.neocities.org/pda-os):

- /e/OS
- AIM-ROM
- AncientROM
- Android Ice Cold Project
- AOSiP (Android Open Source Illusion Project)
- AOSPExtended
- ArrowOS
- Awaken OS
- BaikalOS
- BlissRoms
- Bootleggers ROM
- CAF Extended
- Calyx OS
- CarbonROM
- ColtOS
- Copperhead OS
- CorvusOS
- crDroid
- Cygnus OS
- DerpFest
- Descendant
- Dirty Unicorns
- DivestOS
- Dot OS
- Evolution-X
- GlassROM
- Graphene OS
- Ground Zero Open Source Project
- HavocOS
- iodéOS
- Kang OS
- Kraken Project
- Lineage-X
- LineageOS
- LineageOS microG
- Liquid Remix
- LMODroid
- MoKee
- NitrogenOS
- Nusantara Project
- Octavi OS
- OmniROM
- Paranoid Android
- Pixel Experience
- PixelDust
- Pixys OS
- Potato Open Sauce Project
- Project Elixir
- Project Fluid
- Project Sakura
- Project Xperience
- Project Xtended
- ReloadedOS
- Resurrection Remix
- RevengeOS
- Spark OS
- Spice OS
- Stag OS
- StatixOS
- Stock ROM Ports
- Superior OS
- Syberia Project
- ValidusOS
- VoltageOS
- Wave OS
- ZenXOS